# Do all norms agree on which vector is the longest?

Tags: normed-spaces

Given two norms $\|\cdot\|_a$ and $\|\cdot\|_b$ on a finite-dimensional vector space, could it be that there exist vectors $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2$ such that
$$\|\vec{v}_1\|_a>\|\vec{v}_2\|_a$$
and
$$\|\vec{v}_1\|_b<\|\vec{v}_2\|_b$$
i.e. that the norms "disagree" on which vector is the longest?

Maybe this is related to [norm equivalence](https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.335/norm-equivalence.pdf), but I don't quite see how to get here from there.

Comment: A vector's $\ell_\infty$-norm can be large even if the vector has only one nonzero component.  So our two vectors could be $(1,1,1,1,1)$ and $(0,0,0,0,1.01)$, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Otherwise the norms would only be multiples of each other.

$$\|(30,40)\|_2=50 > 45 =\|(0,45)\|_2$$
$$\|(30,40)\|_\infty=40 < 45 =\|(0,45)\|_\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  An example in $\Bbb{R}^2$:  \begin{align}
    ||(x,y)||_a &= \sqrt{\left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^2 + y^2}  \\
    ||(x,y)||_b &= \sqrt{x^2 + \left( \frac{y}{2} \right)^2}
\end{align}
The sets of constant norm under these two norms are ellipses, but the major axes with the $a$ norm are along the $x$-axis and the major axes for the $b$-norm are long the $y$-axis.  This suggests looking at \begin{align}
    ||(0,1)||_a &= 1 & ||(1,0)||_a &= 1/2  \\
    ||(0,1)||_b &= 1/2 & ||(1,0)||_b &= 1  \text{.}
\end{align}